# How to keep the common React Components fixed in all pages instead of calling them again and again in each page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Suppose in my app I want the ***Header, Navigation Bar and the Breadcrumb and the Calendar Bar *** to be present in all the pages, except in the login page.

So if I mention these Components in App.js file they get rendered in Login Page as well. I obviously don't want the user to see those before doing the login.

In App.js file I am using React Router for Routing purpose.

***Screenshot of the Application the Header,Navigation bar , breadcrumb and calendar bar has been marked***
[screenshot of the Application Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ57b.png)

```js
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import AboutPage from "./components/AboutPage";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import NoPageFound from "./components/NoPageFound";
import InterfaceMonitoringPage from "./pages/InterfaceMonitoringPage";
import ChainPreOrdering from "./pages/ChainPreOrdering";
import ChainOrderMonitoring from "./pages/ChainOrderMonitoringPage";
import JarvisDrillDownPage from "./pages/DrillDownPage";
import MismatchesPage from "./pages/MisMatchesPage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import DevArea from "./pages/DevArea";

//Importing fontawesome icons
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {
  faHome,
  faAtom,
  faUser,
  faCalendarWeek
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
library.add(faHome, faAtom, faUser, faCalendarWeek);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <LoginPage {...props} PageTitle="LoginPage" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/homepage"
          exact
          render={props => <HomePage {...props} PageTitle="HomePage" />}
        />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route
          path="/chainpre-ordermonitoring"
          render={props => (
            <ChainPreOrdering
              {...props}
              PageTitle="Chain Pre-Order Monitoring Page"
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/chainordermonitoring"
          render={props => (
            <ChainOrderMonitoring
              {...props}
              PageTitle="Chain Order Monitoring Page"
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/interface-monitoring-page"
          render={props => (
            <InterfaceMonitoringPage
              {...props}
              PageTitle="Interface Monitoring Page"
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/DevArea"
          render={props => <DevArea {...props} PageTitle="DevArea" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/drilldown-page/:systemName"
          render={props => (
            <JarvisDrillDownPage {...props} PageTitle="Drill Down Page" />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/mismatches-page/:SourceSystem/:EndSystem"
          render={props => (
            <MismatchesPage {...props} PageTitle="Drill Down Page" />
          )}
        />
        <Redirect from="/about-page" to="/about" />
        <Route component={NoPageFound} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

--------**UPDATE**---------
After Brian answer did changes

[But the Calendar Bar should not be present in a homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIQ3d.png)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <LoginPage {...props} PageTitle="LoginPage" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={props => (
            <>
              <JarvisHeader />
              <NavigationBar />
              <JarvisCalendarBar />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <LoginPage {...props} PageTitle="LoginPage" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/homepage"
          render={props => <HomePage {...props} PageTitle="HomePage" />}
        />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route
          path="/chainpre-ordermonitoring"
          render={props => (
            <ChainPreOrdering
              {...props}
              PageTitle="Chain Pre-Order Monitoring Page"
            />
          )}
        />
        
        -----Rest of the Code
        
         </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second switch above the first that is responsible for showing or hiding those components. Something like this maybe?

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">    // Matches on the login path
          <span/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">          // Matches everything else
          <YourSharedComponents />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <LoginPage {...props} PageTitle="LoginPage" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/homepage"
          exact
          render={props => <HomePage {...props} PageTitle="HomePage" />}
        />

        // Condensed
        *******************************

        <Route component={NoPageFound} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Shared Components in your first Switch Section??

Comment: I mean the components that you listed should be included on all pages except the login page.

Comment: Hi @Brian

Meanwhile I also Searched parallely and I have updated the code as below

<Route
          path="/"
          render={props => (
            <>
              <JarvisHeader />
              <NavigationBar />
              <JarvisCalendarBar />
            </>
          )}
        />

Comment: But after doing the changes a new issue came, In home page of the app, I don't want the Calendar bar, Since we have given path"/" without exact for shared components it is getting rendered at homepage as well,  I will attach the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you want to include your sidebar or navbar in every route so you can do this

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

function index(props) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <TopNav {...this.state}/>
            <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={`${match.url}/home`} component={Home} />
                    <Route path={`${match.url}/contact`} component={Contact} />
                    <Route path={`${match.url}/notification`} component={Notification} />
                    <Route component={ErrorPage} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default index;
```

That's how the top navbar will be included in all the route

**Updated: if you want to show it conditionally**

```
{localStorage.getItem('token') !== null && <TopNavBar/>}
```

So the theory is, you have to check whether the user is logged in or not. Suppose a logged in user has a token in local storage. So if the local storage is not null. Which means user is logged in then show the nav bar if the condition is false it will not show nav bar.

Comment: What does Fragment do?

Comment: Hi Moshfiqur 

Thanks for the reply , But suppose I want to to show the Top nav bar only after successful login Then what will be your solution, The Current solution will even show the Nav bar in login page

Comment: For that you will need a nested routing. Are you familiar with nested routing?

Comment: Or you can do another way. You can conditionally load that. Suppose after login you are storing your user login info or token in your local storage. So you can do the updated part of my answer

Comment: @zipzit Fragment is like a wrapper from react. It gives you the power to wrap more than one div or components and use it inside a return. Normally you cannot have more than one div inside a return. If you still need to return two div what we normally did is, wrap that two div inside a parent div. But that is no more a best practice. Because you are creating an extra div with out any cause. That's why react introduced this Fragment. It's just a simple wrapper

Comment: Is that the same as `<> </>`?

Comment: @zipzit Yes, But Fragment is recommended to use by react developer than that